# Google Map v2 Marker Animation

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, google-maps-api-2

Do anyone have idea how this animation's implementation is possible in google map api v2. 
[Check out this here.](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm)
I would like to know how this is done. Please let me know if anyone have any sample code regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For animating polyline routes github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14079312/1472887) that worked for me:

```
final LatLng target = NEW_LOCATION;

final long duration = 400;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
Projection proj = map.getProjection();

Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        if (elapsed > duration) {
            elapsed = duration;
        }
        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
        double lng = t * target.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude;
        double lat = t * target.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude;
        marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        if (t < 1.0) {
            // Post again 10ms later.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        } else {
            // animation ended
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
This line giving error ... "Incompatible type"

Comment: make sure you import:
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

And not the other Interpolator.

Comment: i found a bug. Is necessary to add this two lines:
      if (elapsed>duration)
       elapsed=duration;

Answer (score 7):

You are welcome to change the position of a `Marker` at any point by calling `setPosition()`. You are welcome to change the position of the "camera" (i.e., the map's center and zoom level) at any point by applying a `CameraUpdate` object using `moveTo()` or `animateTo()` on `GoogleMap`. Combining these with a light timing loop (e.g., using `postDelayed()`) should allow you to achieve a similar animation effect.

Comment: Can you please provide some code so that i can get better idea of implementation. I have tried to animate the map using CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy method.. its working fine even. But not found any way of animating the on the path on the map.

Comment: @Grishu: "Can you please provide some code so that i can get better idea of implementation" -- I do not have any lying around that handles your scenario. "But not found any way of animating the on the path on the map" -- you have to find "the path on the map" yourself, using some Web service (presumably), then update the `Marker` positions to be various points along that path.

Answer (score 0):

Great news is that he Google Map API v2 gives the new Camera controls.
You can check the new features and how to use them directly [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97HLa739rXU&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_5ci9j-iwC3P9Va3Y32-aL)  on the Youtube channel of the Android developers team.

It also provides animate, tilt, bearing ... but I think the video is very detailed and also talks about applications like the one in your example.

Have fun, and give me a link when you finish your app.