# Map Marker icon animation (Google Maps API V2 for Android)

Tags: android, drawable, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

On a custom event, I need my `Marker` to update its drawable 6 times (basically, I want the `Marker` to grow and shrink 3 times with a delay of 0.5 s between each growth and each shrink) so it notifies the user of said event.

Is there any way to achieve this without actually having to remove the `Marker` and adding it again with a different `Drawable`?

Comment: If you want to grow and shrink the image, you can use 2 Makers and use `Marker.setVisible`.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/25765972/3020568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do it today without actually removing the marker and adding it again with another drawable. I have just done so myself in an attempt to create a progress bar. It works, but it is an awkward way of doing it.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14883628/250526) for a good explanation in another thread.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Had to do it with an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 10):

Marker has a new function added as of rev.7 of API v2. [Marker.setIcon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#setIcon%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor%29). Have fun animating.