# How do I achieve smooth animation of the location marker in android on a google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

In android with Google Map API V2 I call map.setMyLocationEnabled(true). The blue dot now shows my location on the map. As my location changes the blue dot moves, but the movement is very choppy. It jumps from location to location regardless of the frequency with which I set the location. How can I achieve a smooth motion of the blue location dot. Is it possible using this mechanism? Or do I have to take over the placement of the dot and its animation myself?

Thanks,
Howard

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340921/map-marker-icon-animation-google-maps-api-v2-for-android

Comment: @MisterSmith the articles you point to refer to using your own marker as opposed to the built in one provided when setMyLocationEnabled is called. Can you confirm that using ones own marker is the only option?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you update your Camera