# Is it possible add animation icon marker on Google map android api?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I want add marker with animation icon,
but It doesn't work.
Google map api in ios, it's simple. just set icon property with imageview that have animation.

```
GMSMarker *newMarker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition...];
newMarker.icon = animateImageView;
```

but in android, set icon with BitMapDescriptor.
anyway, I try like this, but it doesn't work.
just first image showed.

```
ImageView animImgView = new ImagView(context);
//walking_person_anim.xml - <animation-list>...</animation-list> 
animImgView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.walking_person_anim));

animImgView.measure(...,...);
Bitmap markerBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(..., .., Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(markerBitmap);

AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) anim.getDrawable();
ad.setBound(0,0,...,...);
ad.draw(markerBitmap);
ad.start();

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(...)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap));
```

what's problem? animation icon impossible in android google map?

Comment: which type of animation icon you want to put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you will get a better solution from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2)

On that link there is a question to how to Animating markers on Google Maps V2