# I want to animate my google maps marker like grow animation when marker is set to visible and shrink animation when marker visibility is gone

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want this animation like uber app when you choose vehicle type the selected vehicle cars appear on map with growing animation and goes away like shrinking animation.
I searched a lot for the animation but couldn't find any related answer .Please guide me how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for adding the marker

```
private void addDriver(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!(markersList.containsKey(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_id"))))
        {

            //   Log.e("ADDDD","MARKERRRR");

            final Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_lat")),Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_long"))))
                    .snippet(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_id")));
            marker.setTag(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("vehicle_type"));
          /*  Bitmap markerIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            pulseMarker(markerIcon, marker, 3000);*/
            markersList.put(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_id"),marker);

            /*final Marker marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_lat")),Double.parseDouble(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("user_long")))).title("Marker"));
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
            final Bitmap target = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(target);
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            animator.setDuration(2000);
            animator.setStartDelay(4000);
            final Rect originalRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            final RectF scaledRect = new RectF();
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation)
                {
                    float scale = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    scaledRect.set(0, 0, originalRect.right * scale, originalRect.bottom * scale);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, originalRect, scaledRect, null);
                    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(target));
                }
            });
            animator.start();*/


        }
    }
}
```

by this code i add the marker .Now i want my marker to appear on map with animation instead of direct popup on maps.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2

Comment: no its not i want to animate my marker icon with grow and shrink animation.i dont want to move marker.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Chisko check the code

Comment: why are you guys giving negative ratings to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
final Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_temperature_kelvin_black_48dp);
final Bitmap target = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(target);
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
animator.setDuration(500);
animator.setStartDelay(1000);
final Rect originalRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
final RectF scaledRect = new RectF();
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        float scale = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        scaledRect.set(0, 0, originalRect.right * scale, originalRect.bottom * scale);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, originalRect, scaledRect, null);
        marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(target));
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Try this code to do a grow animation. If it works try to do this inside a function and call it from a handler

Comment: no it doesnt works marker just blinks and sets on the map