# How to set Map marker Icon Animation in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, google-maps-markers, android-mapview

[image]

here i attached my screen image.
I want to give water wave Animation to the blue circle which is seen in image in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972401/google-map-v2-marker-animation

Comment: https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689

Comment: hey NoumanGhaffar, i want to make continuous animation for that blue circle like increase size and decrease size of outer blue circe.
they both are image. I have attach layout to the marker ..
I need  Animation XML for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Map v2 Marker Animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972401/google-map-v2-marker-animation)